# Angular Property Binding throwing a 404

Tags: angular

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
<div class="albumsContainer">
  <div *ngFor="let album of albums" class="albumContainer">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="albumCover" [src]="album.albumCover" alt="" />
    </a>
    <h4>{{ album.albumTitle }}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

The error I get is the following: Battle-Lines.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:4200/Battle-Lines.jpg 404 (Not Found), which is repeated for each album. Both of my image files are located in the assets folder under src which is listed under the assets array in my angular.json. Why is the image being fetched this way? Shouldn't it be able to just grab the string from the component class and set the src property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of "album.albumCover" ?

If your image is in the assets, you need the path to the image in [src] value

Example : "assets/covers/battle-lines.jpg"

Comment: So how can I bind the URL? [src]="assets/album.albumCover" does not work since assets/ is a string while the rest is a component property. How can I embed a string when property binding?

Comment: like this ```" 'assets/' + album.albumCover"```